# filter "items" with Jquery via a Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have Dropdown at the top of the page and a long list (83 boxes in rows of 4) underneath it.

Here is the scenario:

I select a state from the list of states in the dropdown, and the item in the list that do not match the state fade out allowing the matching items to "pop up" to the top. Once you go back to the default, all the others fade back in.

If there are no matching items to a state, I would display a message "no options found"

I am pretty sure I have seen this done on portfolios somewhere, but I really have no clue on how to achieve this. Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this, or can point me in the right direction?

```
<select id="filter" name="filter">
    <option value="-1">Filter items</option>
    <option value="sc">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="nc">North Carolina</option>
</select>



<div id="container">

<div class="box state-nc"></div>
<div class="box state-sc"></div>
<div class="box state-nc"></div>
<div class="box state-sc"></div>
<div class="box state-nc"></div>
<div class="box state-sc"></div>
<div class="box state-nc"></div>
<div class="box state-sc"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Hint: Get an event fired on the change of select element's value and then perform the fading operations on the rest of the elements, depending upon their state

Comment: check out the [quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/). i have implemented this using a select combobox also..

Comment: You really need to show your work so far so we can at least suggest a solution.

Comment: @weexpectedTHIS, I have updated the question with a bit of sample code (the basics of the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a fixed width/height for the 83 items and float them all to the left, so they naturally form rows of 4 items and will re-flow ("pop up") when some get hidden.

Give each item a class like "state-ca" or "state-or" (or if you prefer data-state="ca" or data-state="or"). Then something like this:

```
var $all_items = $('.item');
var state = $dropdown.val();
var $items = $('.item[class!="state-' + state + '"]');
// or this:
// var $items = $('.item[data-state!="' + state + '"]');
if ($items.size() == $all_items) {
  $all_items.fadeOut();
  // show "no options found" instead
} else {
  $all_items.show();
  $items.fadeOut();
}
```

(Not tested, so I'm sure you'll need to make some adjustments.)